# How to migrate an object which has been persisted with NSKeyedArchiver?

Tags: ios, migration, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, object-persistence

I'm using a version of **[Archiver](https://github.com/patlachance/openstack-ios/blame/master/Classes/Archiver.m)** and have run into an issue.

In a previous version of my project a class, *Challenge* was serialized to disk

```
//v1.0
@interface Challenge : NSObject<NSCoding>
{
  ...
  @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *challengeId;
  @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL isCompleted;
  ...
}
```

Now, in version 1.1 of the app the desire is to change the *Challenge* object by adding two new @properties.

```
//v1.1
@interface Challenge : NSObject<NSCoding>
{
  ...
  @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *challengeId;
  @property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL isCompleted;
  ...
  @property (nonatomic) BOOL isActive;
  @property (nonatomic) NSInteger completeCount;
}
```

My issue is this, when Archiver attempts to decode the *Challenge* object, because the two new properties exist (e.g. *Challenge* v1.1 doesn't match copy or alloc pattern for *Challenge* v1.0) then an exception is thrown.

Essentially, has anyone migrated a NSEncoding object and come accross a similar scenario and what techniques did you employ to overcome the issue?

**Options I've considered**

So far I've attempted to insert a superclass above *Challenge* in the object tree but couldn't get it to function.

Also, I've considered using a two step migration, i.e. release v1.1 which decodes persisted challenges in the old format and persists a new type of object *NewChallenge* in preparation for v1.2 - this seems over-complex to me (considering I just want to add two properties).

I've considered extending Challenge and having the properties exist in a subclass, but this would mean changing a lot of code which is expecting to see a *Challenge* object.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many Thanks to **Mike Mayo** (@greenisus) the original author of Archiver for the clue to what was going on...

It turns out that during decoding it is possible to check for the existence of any given key. The Archiver project uses the function below to decode objects; so at the point where it could try to decode a non existent key put a check if the coder knows about said key - if it doesn't the skip that iteration of the for loop with a continue clause.

```
- (void) autoDecode:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    NSDictionary *properties = [self properties];

    for (NSString *key in properties)
    {
        if (![coder containsValueForKey:key]) {
            continue;
        }

        NSString *capitalizedKey = [key stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:[[key substringToIndex:1] capitalizedString]];
        NSString *selectorString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"set%@:", capitalizedKey];
        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(selectorString);
        NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector:selector];

        if (!signature) {
            continue;
        }

        ...
```

In my case the encoded objects also caused a crash when attempting to decode hash and description, hence the requirement for the second continue clause.